# How to place in the corner (bottom end) of column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I put a widget/compose in bottom end corner of Column?

```
Column(
 verticalArrangement = ,
 horizontalAlignment = 
) { // omitted codes }
```

I only find horizontal and vertical position to it? IS there a way to put a widget/compose in bottom end?

I can’t find a parameter in column to place widget/compose in bottom end corner

Comment: For this purpose, you must use Box

Answer (score 3):

For a better understanding of Box, see the example below

[image]

```
@Composable
fun BoxExample2() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
 
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart),
            text = "TopStart"
        )
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
            text = "TopCenter"
        )
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd),
            text = "TopEnd"
        )
 
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
            text = "CenterStart"
        )
 
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            text = "Center"
        )
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
            text = "CenterEnd"
        )
 
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart),
            text = "BottomStart"
        )
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            text = "BottomCenter"
        )
        Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            text = "BottomEnd"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `Column` to put a Composable in the bottom end corner you have to use:

```
Column(
    modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
) { 

    Button(onClick = {}){
        Text("Button")
    }

}
```

[image]

In general the attributes `verticalArrangement` and `horizontalAlignment` specify the vertical arrangement and the horizontal alignment  of the layout's children according **to the space occupied** by the `Column`.

With:

```
Column(
    modifier=Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(80.dp).background(Yellow),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
)
```

[image]